# How to import VNStat data from 32 bit ubuntu to 64 bit?

Tags: 14.04

I want to backup vnstst log and import it into new ubuntu system. Currently Iam in 32 bit ubuntu 14.04 and planning for 64 bit 14.04LTS. 
I have read this "http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2053507" . Where they said that "databases from 32 bit machines and 64 bit machines apparently are not compatible. I had noticed a slight size difference between them".

How to make them compatible with 64 bit os?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options available for getting a vnStat database created in a 32bit system to be readable in a 64bit system:

1. Use the (somewhat experimental) database convertion tool: http://humdi.net/vnstat/dbconvert.c
2. Export the database using the --dumpdb parameter to a file in the 32bit system, then in the 64bit system, using vnStat 1.12 or later, use the --importdb parameter to import the database from the previously created text file

Both should give the same end result. Option 1 is simpler and isn't limited on having also the 32bit system available as long as the database files are still available. Option 2 allows you to also modify the database data if needed but will require more work since 14.04 doesn't include vnStat version 1.12.